# Grep with windows, words created in text file without spaces

Tags: windows, shell, text, grep, newline

I am using grep to take all the four letter words out of a dictionary text file and place them into a new text file.

This command should work with Unix however on windows it does not.

I need one word per line, on windows it gives me all the words but all piled together without spaces.

This is the grep command I'm using:

```
grep "^[a-z]\{4\}$" dictionaryfilename > outputfilename
```

I believe it's something to do with a difference in newline characters between Unix and windows?

Anyway I'm not sure how to make a fix for windows with this could someone please help.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: what implementation of grep on Windows are you using?

Comment: can you try with word boundaries? grep -i "\b[a-z]{4}\b" dictionary > output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably have a UNIX-formatted textfile (newlines without carriage returns), which looks like one big line in Windows; `grep` just deals in whatever the system says is 'a line', so it has little to do with the problem.

Try converting the file from LF to CRLF and see if you get better results.